# Sending mails async get executed after view result is returned

Tags: c#, email, asynchronous

I have a the following controller method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendToAllUsers(SentMailToAllUsersModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var mail = MailService.SendMailToAllUsers(model.Body, model.Title);
            await mail;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Which is calling this method on the mail service

```
public Task SendMailToAllUsers(string content, string title)
    {

        var users = UserService.GetAllUsers();
        var mailTemplates =  users.Result.AsParallel().Select(user =>
        {

            var mailTemplate = new MastersMailTemplate(user);
            mailTemplate.HtmlEmailTemplate = content;
            mailTemplate.Subject = title;
            mailTemplate.From = _fromEmail;

            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MailProvider.SendEmailAsync(mailTemplate.CreateMailMessage(), new ResultDescription()).ConfigureAwait(false));
        }).ToArray();

        return Task.WhenAll(mailTemplates);




    }
```

This method is triggering the mail provider that executes this method:

```
public Task<IResultDescription> SendEmailAsync(MailMessage message, IResultDescription rd)
    {
        // Create our SMTP Client
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = SmtpServer;
        client.Port = SmtpServerPort;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpServerUsername, SmtpServerPassword);
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        if (AppSettings.IsInTestMode)
        {

            Log.Info("Test mode check: Removing all emails and replace to test");
            message.To.Clear();
            foreach (var email in AppSettings.DefaultTestEmail)
            {
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
            }
        }

        client.Timeout = 10;
        Log.Info("Sending Email to" + message.To.FirstOrDefault());
        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try{
                client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    client.Dispose();
                    message.Dispose();
                };
                await client.SendAsync(message);
                rd.Success = true;
                return rd;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error("Email not send");
                rd.Success = false;
                if (rd.Errors == null)
                {

                    IList<string> errors = new List<string>();
                    errors.Add(e.Message);
                    rd.Errors = errors;
                }
                else
                {
                    rd.Errors.Add(e.Message);
                }

                return rd;
            }
        });

        return task;




    }
```

The problem is that the result view is returned before any mails where sent.
The controller is not waiting untill all mails are sent.

How can I make sure that the controller only continues execution when all tasks in the mail service are completed?

Comment: Why are you doing `await client.SendAsync(...)` if you could just do `client.Send(...)`?

Comment: Thanks elgonzo, this did the job!

Comment: Note that the *SendCompleted* event is not fired for `client.Send(...)`. However, that is not really a problem, bacause you can put the code of your *SendCompleted* handler right behind `client.Send(...)` (also note, that whenever an exception occurs those .Dispose() calls are not being made)

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, do not use `Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, `Parallel`, or PLINQ on ASP.NET. There is always a better way. In this case, just use `async` and `await`:

```
public async Task SendMailToAllUsersAsync(string content, string title)
{
  var users = await UserService.GetAllUsersAsync();
  var mailTemplates = users.AsParallel().Select(user =>
  {
    var mailTemplate = new MastersMailTemplate(user);
    mailTemplate.HtmlEmailTemplate = content;
    mailTemplate.Subject = title;
    mailTemplate.From = _fromEmail;
    return MailProvider.SendEmailAsync(mailTemplate.CreateMailMessage());
  }).ToArray();
  return await Task.WhenAll(mailTemplates);
}
```

Similarly for your inner method:

```
public Task<IResultDescription> SendEmailAsync(MailMessage message, IResultDescription rd)
{
  using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
  using (message)
  {
    client.Host = SmtpServer;
    client.Port = SmtpServerPort;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpServerUsername, SmtpServerPassword);
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    if (AppSettings.IsInTestMode)
    {
      Log.Info("Test mode check: Removing all emails and replace to test");
      message.To.Clear();
      foreach (var email in AppSettings.DefaultTestEmail)
      {
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
      }
    }

    client.Timeout = 10;
    Log.Info("Sending Email to" + message.To.FirstOrDefault());
    try
    {
      await client.SendAsync(message);
      rd.Success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Log.Error("Email not send");
      rd.Success = false;
      if (rd.Errors == null)
      {
        IList<string> errors = new List<string>();
        errors.Add(e.Message);
        rd.Errors = errors;
      }
      else
      {
        rd.Errors.Add(e.Message);
      }
    }
    return rd;
  }
}
```

Remember, `async` makes things *easy*. If the `async` code is excessively complicated, check for A Better Way. I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that you may find useful.

Comment: Hi Sir, sorry for reviving this thread. But I'm having problem. When I was running my program is localhost it works fine but when I hosted my website the mail is sending but SendMailAsync never returns. Is this a deadlock problem? I'm just new with this kind of stuffs I hope you can help me Sir, thank you in advance. Here's my controller: http://pastie.org/10907763 Tried to edit `await smtp.SendMailAsync(message)` to `await smtp.SendMailAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);` but still it never returns. Really hope you can help me Sir. Thank you. Have a g'day. :)

Comment: I took a look through the code, and nothing jumps out at me. One thing
to check is that you are targeting .NET 4.5 or higher, *and* have set
`targetFramework` to `4.5` or higher in your `web.config`. The code itself
looks fine and shouldn't be causing a deadlock. If it's not a 4.5-targeting issue, then I recommend that you reduce the problem to the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce it, and post it as your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `SendMailToAllUsers` method. I think you need to `await` the `MailProvider.SendEmailAsync` call. If you don't do this, the task started by `Task.Factory.StartNew` will be considered complete as soon as that method executes. Because the method is actually asynchronous it only kicks off the operation, it doesn't wait for its completion. If you `await` the result that should fix the problem.

Change your code to:

```
public Task SendMailToAllUsers(string content, string title)
    {
        var users = UserService.GetAllUsers();
        var mailTemplates =  users.Result.AsParallel().Select(user =>
        {

            var mailTemplate = new MastersMailTemplate(user);
            mailTemplate.HtmlEmailTemplate = content;
            mailTemplate.Subject = title;
            mailTemplate.From = _fromEmail;

            // Await the result of the lambda expression
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => await MailProvider.SendEmailAsync(mailTemplate.CreateMailMessage(), new ResultDescription()).ConfigureAwait(false));
        }).ToArray();

        return Task.WhenAll(mailTemplates);
    }
```